# Launch file not well-configured

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using polar_scan_matcher package to use along with my own package called pcd_robot. The pcd_robot is publishing a topic of "/scan" and instead of using data from their dataset, I want to use the laser scan data from my own one. This can be done by tweaking some lines in the launch file. The original one looks like this:

```
<launch>

  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" 
    args="-d $(find polar_scan_matcher)/demo/demo.vcg"/>

  <node pkg="rosbag" type="rosbag" name="rosbag" 
    args="play $(find polar_scan_matcher)/demo/demo.bag --delay=5 --clock"/>

  <node pkg="polar_scan_matcher" type="psm_node" name="psm_node" output="screen">
    <param name="max_error" value="0.20"/>
    <param name="search_window" value="100"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" 
    args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 40" />

</launch>
```

Hence, I have edited it and commented the unused rosbag input data. The altered launch file is as follows:

```
<launch>

  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" 
    args="-d $(find polar_scan_matcher)/demo/demo.vcg"/>

  <!--
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="rosbag" name="rosbag" 
    args="play $(find polar_scan_matcher)/demo/demo.bag --delay=5 --clock"/>
  -->

  <node pkg="pcd_robot" type="publisher_node" name="publisher_node" 
    <remap from="/scan" to="scan"/>

  <node pkg="polar_scan_matcher" type="psm_node" name="psm_node" output="screen">
    <param name="max_error" value="0.20"/>
    <param name="search_window" value="100"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" 
    args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 40" />

</launch>
```

However, when I run "roslaunch pcd_robot try.launch" I got an error saying that "Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token): line 10, column 58
"

Is it something wrong with my launch file or my command, perhaps?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12081/launch-file-not-well-configured/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The node tag doesn't end (> missing) and is not closed (< /node>).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-24**:
@arebgun: now, I got your point..thanks.

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-11-24**:
Something like this doesn't work though: <!-- -- -->

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-24**:
@arebgun: But if we refer to "http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xmlcomment.php", it is normal to have a block comment like that..Please correct me if I'm wrong..

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-11-24**:
You can't have a double dash (--) inside an xml comment tag which is pretty annoying.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-24**:
Thanks, it is somehow true your suggestion, another strange thing is it is only working when I completely deleted the commented lines..

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-24**:
I've tried like this, it doesn't work either:

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-24**:
I've tried like the one you type above, I got the same error.